# best tree wavelet packet for python

Tags: python, matlab, quadtree, wavelet

I have a question related to wavelet packet decomposition.

I need to compute a best tree(basis) from complete (full) tree (quad-tree). This can be done by MATLAB's function [besttree](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/wavelet/ref/besttree.html). Unfortunately, I can't use  m-files in my program.

I write my program on python and [pywt](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/) attracted my attention, but in this module no function to calculate best tree. 
Are there any modules, library, or some examples in which the calculated best tree wavelet packet decomposition (quad-tree) on C++/C or python? Is there any possibility to convert m-files to C++/C or python?

Answer (score 0):

please check this link:

this To compile Matlab code to C++, use the mcc command:
http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html;jsessionid=351100b26b237828d538922ffe69

To use c++ libraries in Matlab, use Mex:
http://www.mathworks.de/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html